# How to load list of patients in angular component which relies in main navigation component (i.e. that holds a router-outlet) from another component

Tags: angular

I have angular application which contains have a **search-patient** component which contains list of patients loads at first page refresh, the **search-patient** component relies in **main-navigation** component (i.e. that contains **router-outlet**). Now I have another **add-patient** component which displays in **main-navigation** component (i.e. within the **router-outlet**), Now I have to refresh or update the list of patient in **search-patient** component when I save or update the patient.

Hope you understand the scenario

Thanks

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

if data is fetched on component intialization i.e on ngOnit() of child search-patient component then adding to the database from child add-patient component and redirecting to the search-patient component the results should be updated. where the main-component is the parent with router-outlet.

i.e i believe you use HttpClient library that gives an observable to fetch data from apis.

if its not the case you can create a service (for example DataService) with an observable like

```
hasUpdatedOrSaved:BehaviourSubject<boolean>(true);
```

with a method that gives back observable

```
getSavedOrUpdatedStatus():Observable{
 return hasUpdatedOrSaved.asObservable();
}
```

and in child search-patient component you can subscribe to it using the service object

```
getSavedOrUpdatedStatusSubscription:Subscription;

constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

ngOnit():void{
  this.getSavedOrUpdatedStatusSubscription = this.dataService.subscribe(result=>{
   if(result){
      this.fetchData(); //call function to fetch data
   }
});
}
ngOnDestroy(){
  this.getSavedOrUpdatedStatusSubscription.unscubscribe();
}
```

the intial value is true for the observable hence it runs first time thereafter in every update or addition 'true' value is to be emitted so that fetching runs again, so the add-patient component having methods for update and add will have :

```
 constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

addPatient(){
   //adding
   this.dataService.hasUpdatedOrSaved.next(true);  //emitt to fetch data again after addition
}
updatePatient(){
   //updating
this.dataService.hasUpdatedOrSaved.next(true); //emitt to fetch data again after updation
}
```

You can use it across any components across your angular app